# Select the smallest range?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, range

I am working with a VBA that should formate a selected range of cells, and only the active cells in the selection.

I have figured out how to work it if my selection contains only whole columns.
But if I my sellection is a certain range within the active cells, I can not get it to work.

Is there a way to choose the range that contains the smallest numbers of cells.
In this case, to see which of `rng` and `rng1` that is "smallest".

```
Sub FormatColumn()
Dim rngMyRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Start As Range
Set rngMyRange = Selection
Dim A As Range, B As Range

With rngMyRange
    i = .Rows(1).Row
    j = .Columns(1).Column
    ii = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    jj = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
End With

Set A = Cells(i, j)
Set B = Cells(ii, jj)
Set C = Cells(i, jj).End(xlDown)

Set rng = Range(A, B)
Set rng1 = Range(A, C)

With rng
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

With rng1
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 20
End With

End Sub
```

Hence, I just want to have one of the two formating rules in the end (divided like this to see what is happening with the two ranges) and to only format the range with the smallest numbers of cells in it.

Comment: `rng.count` will give you the number of cells.

Comment: Also only one cell can ever be active (I think). In your code `rng` is the same as `rngMyRange` ?

Comment: No, they are two different ranges, so that is no problem. rngMyRange is the Selection I have chosen from the worksheet, and rng is only the active cells from that range.

Comment: No sorry that is not right. `rng` runs from the top left corner of `rngMyRange` to the bottom right. And rng will always be smaller than rng1.

Comment: Well, depends on how the range is chosen. If I have numbers/text in A1:D200, I can choose my range in "two different" ways, either whole columns (A:B) or only some of the cells (A1:B30) and that will give two different outcomes. But at least I got it to work the way I want now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of @SRJ

```
Sub FormatColumn()
Dim rngMyRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Start As Range
Set rngMyRange = Selection
Dim A As Range, B As Range, rng1 As Range, C As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long, jj As Long

With rngMyRange
    i = .Rows(1).Row
    j = .Columns(1).Column
    ii = .Rows(.Rows.count).Row
    jj = .Columns(.Columns.count).Column
End With
Debug.Print i, j, ii, jj
Set A = Cells(i, j)
Set B = Cells(ii, jj)
Set C = Cells(i, jj).End(xlDown)

Set rng = Range(A, B)
Set rng1 = Range(A, C)

If rng.count < rng1.Count Then
    With rng
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
Else
With rng1
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 20
End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, the update came there, excatly the change I had to make to get it to work!